# JQuery add class dynamically to first element with a particular class

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have dynamically created bootstrap [accordions](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse) containing dynamically created groups in each. I want to add the `in` class to the first group in each accordion, which opens it as you can see in the linked bootstrap example.

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h6 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordionToggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#dynamicId" href="#dynamicId">
                Title
            </a>
        </h6>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="dynamicId">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
...
```

There can be any number of `.panel.panel-default` which can contain any number of `.panel-collapse.collapse`

Here is what I have tried, as well as some other variations, to add the `in` class to the first `.panel-collapse.collapse` of each `.panel.panel-default` but I keep ending up with it adding the class to each one and not just the first.

```
$(".panel.panel-default").each(function (index) {
    $(this).children(".panel-collapse.collapse:first").addClass("in");
});

$(".panel.panel-default").each(function (index) {
    $(this).find(".panel-collapse.collapse:first").addClass("in");
});

$(".panel.panel-default").each(function (index) {
    $(this).children(".panel-collapse.collapse").first().addClass("in");
});
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Your code should work as expected. So please try to replicate your issue on jsfiddle

Comment: Sounds like you need to wrap the `.each()` in a function and call that function  **after** the 'accordians' are added

Comment: @RobSedgwick You think it's an issue with them being added dynamically then?

Comment: @aw04:you should better create problem fiddle.

Comment: yes, maybe the .each() is running on elements that are not there yet ? ( need more code on how the 'accordions' are added )

Comment: eg something like - **accordiansadded()** *then run the* .each()

Comment: @RobSedgwick That makes sense, I will try that. This is done in asp.net mvc and I'm iterating through my model to create these. Also why it's hard for me to replicate in a js fiddle for everyone who's asking, sorry!

Comment: sounds likely ( as you said 'dynamic' added elements - via ajax ? ) , create a function called say , `function addInClass() { $("selectors).each() ... ` and call that after you have done with your javascript iterations adding the markup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate the `panel-group`, because I think what you are trying to do is to expand the first item in each accordion

```
$(".panel-group").each(function (index) {
    $(this).children(".panel-collapse.collapse:first").addClass("in");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KrnYh/)

Comment: The .panel-collapse.collapse is the group and I'm iterating over it's parent, how is this different than what I have?

Comment: @aw04 can you check the attached fiddle... does the markup there simulate yours

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".panel-collapse.collapse:first").addClass("in");
});
```

It works for me.